# Can't query associated table

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a simple todo / author model where todo has a author_id field.

The models are defined as follows:

```
defmodule TodoElixir.User.Author do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "authors" do
    field :email, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true   
    field :hash, :string
    has_many :todos, Main.Todo

    timestamps()
  end
```

Here I get a

> warning: invalid association `todo` in schema TodoElixir.User.Author:
>   associated schema Main.Todo does not exist

And the todo model:

```
defmodule TodoElixir.Main.Todo do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "todos" do
    field :date, :date
    field :description, :string
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :author, User.Author

    timestamps()
  end
```

I also have a migration for each:

```
defmodule TodoElixir.Repo.Migrations.CreateAuthors do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:authors) do
      add :name, :string
      add :email, :string
      add :hash, :string
      has_many :todos, Main.Todo

      timestamps()
    end

  end
end

defmodule TodoElixir.Repo.Migrations.CreateTodos do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:todos) do
      add :title, :string
      add :description, :string
      add :date, :date
      add :author_id, references(:authors)

      timestamps()
    end

  end
end
```

If I remove `has_many :todos, Main.Todo` from the module, it compiles and I can query 
http://localhost:4000/api/todos but the author field is not set.

I've tried using preload and assoc but following https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/ecto/associations/ the association should be automatic...

In the todo controller I have:

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    todos = Main.list_todos()
    render(conn, "index.json", todos: todos)
  end
```

and list_todos =

```
  def list_todos do
    Repo.all(Todo)
  end
```

EDIT:

In the controller I put:

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    todos = Repo.all(Todo) |> Repo.preload(:author)
    render(conn, "index.json", todos: todos)
  end
```

I see the query in the console:

> [debug] Processing with TodoElixirWeb.TodoController.index/2
>   Parameters: %{}   Pipelines: [:api] [debug] QUERY OK source="todos"
>   db=6.3ms decode=1.7ms queue=0.8ms SELECT t0."id", t0."date",
>   t0."description", t0."title", t0."author_id", t0."inserted_at",
>   t0."updated_at" FROM "todos" AS t0 [] [debug] QUERY OK
>   source="authors" db=0.6ms queue=1.0ms SELECT a0."id", a0."email",
>   a0."name", a0."hash", a0."inserted_at", a0."updated_at", a0."id" FROM
>   "authors" AS a0 WHERE (a0."id" = $1)

Which looks good to me, but the JSON result:

```
{"data":[{"date":null,"description":"we need to do this","id":1,"title":"My first todo"}]}
```

Should I tell Elixir to add the associations in the JSON response as well? How?

Comment: I tried has_many :todos, TodoElixir.Main.Todo which compiles with no warning, but I still can't see the association...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from the requirements needed

> I have simple todo / author model where todo has an author_id field that needs to parse as JSON.

- First have a migration

```
defmodule TodoElixir.Repo.Migrations.CreateAuthorsTodos do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    # create authors
    create table(:authors) do
      add :name, :string
      add :email, :string
      add :hash, :string


      timestamps()
    end

    flush() # this one will execute migration commands above [see Ecto.Migration flush/0][1] 

   # create todos
   create table(:todos) do
      add :title, :string
      add :description, :string
      add :date, :date
      add :author_id, references(:authors)

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

- Set Tables and relationships for each tables. You can view [Ecto Schema](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html) and see different functions to set them. In this case will be using **has_many and belongs_to**

```
defmodule TodoElixir.User.Author do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "authors" do
    field :email, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true   
    field :hash, :string
    has_many :todos, TodoElixir.Main.Todo 

    timestamps()
  end
end

defmodule TodoElixir.User.Todo do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "todos" do
    field :date, :date
    field :description, :string
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :author, TodoElixir.User.Author # -> this will be used upon preload in your controller

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

- In your controller, to preload you can do it like this
- first alias your resources: **Author, Todo, and your Repo**
- then create function to **call all TODO preloading AUTHOR**.

```
  alias TodoElixir.User.{Author, Todo} # -> your tables
  alias TodoElixir.Repo # -> call your repo

  def index(conn, _params) do
    todos = list_todos()
    render(conn, "index.json", todos: todos)
  end

 defp list_todos() do
   Todo
   |> Repo.all()
   |> Repo.preload(:author)
 end
```

- Now to render json associated with author, let's go back to TODO and AUTHOR schema
- to load them as JSON, you can use either [JASON](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/readme.html#content) or [POISON](https://hexdocs.pm/poison/Poison.html).
- for this one we will use **JASON**

```
# in your endpoint.ex
# set up Jason using this one.

plug Plug.Parsers,
  parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
  pass: ["*/*"],
  json_decoder: Jason


# in your TODO and AUTHOR schemas derived the fields that you need in each tables.

defmodule TodoElixir.User.Todo do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  # this is the key parsing them
  @derive Jason.Encoder
  defstruct %{
       :date,
       :description,
       :title,
       :author # -> This will show author. take note, if you do not preload author via TODO, this will cause error
  }

  schema "todos" do
    field :date, :date
    field :description, :string
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :author, TodoElixir.User.Author

    timestamps()
  end
end

# since we call AUTHOR inside TODO, we also need to derived fields from Author. # Otherwise it will cause error.

defmodule TodoElixir.User.Author do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  # you can also call fields that you want to parse.
  @derive Jason.Encoder
  defstruct %{
      :email,
      :name,
      :id
  }

  schema "authors" do
    field :email, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true   
    field :hash, :string
    has_many :todos, TodoElixir.Main.Todo 

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

1. Now in your **VIEW**, you can set up like this one

```
   def render("index.json", %{todos: todos}) do 
    todos
   end
```

**Additional notes:** if you don't want to derive fields in your schema and still want to parse them as json, you can do it like this.

```
# in your CONTROLLER, 

 alias TodoElixir.User.{Author, Todo} # -> your tables
 alias TodoElixir.Repo # -> call your repo

 def index(conn, _params) do
    todos = list_todos()
    render(conn, "index.json", todos: todos)
 end

 defp list_todos() do
   Todo
   |> Repo.all()
   |> Repo.preload(:author)
 end


# In your VIEW, you can manipulate the transformation you want.

 def render("index.json", %{todos: todos}) do
  todos
  |> Enum.map(fn f -> 
  %{
    # you can add additional fields in here.
    title: f.title,
    author: f.author.name
  }
  end)

 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [preload](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3) the relation explicitly:

```
todos = Main.list_todos()
|> Repo.preload(:todos) # don't forget to alias repo
```

If it throws an error then the relation is not referenced correctly, otherwise it will make a join query and you will have all relations in `todos`.

If you read the [has_many/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3) documentation, you can notice the following:

> :foreign_key - Sets the foreign key, this should map to a field on the
>   other schema, defaults to the underscored name of the current schema
>   suffixed by _id

So in the case you have a foreign key with a different name you can explicitly use this parameter:

```
has_many :todos, Main.Todo, foreign_key: :author_id
```

Also you shouldn't add relations to migrations, in migrations you define only the structure and modifications you do to tables, so remove:

```
has_many :todos, Main.Todo
```

You can read more about what you can do in migrations [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html).

Comment: Doing this in the controller I get : schema TodoElixir.Main.Todo does not have association :todos

Comment: I made an edit at the end of the post if you want to take a look. I get no error now, the query looks good but the json is missing the association

Comment: you need to explicitly render it, take a look at views there you should have `todo_view` and `author_view`, you can change them to render the required parts you need

Comment: thanks, it works but it's so painful to work with associations... and the documentation lacks a lot of concrete examples :(

Comment: that is not true, it is very well documented, moreover elixir encourages reading source code if the documentation is not clear. Once you understand how to work with them, you will find how powerful of a construct they are.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here: `has_many :todos, Main.Todo` on `TodoElixir.Repo.Migrations.CreateAuthors`. It should be like

```
defmodule TodoElixir.Repo.Migrations.CreateAuthors do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:authors) do
      add :name, :string
      add :email, :string
      add :hash, :string

      timestamps()
    end

  end
end
```

Then you can query after preload data

```
def list_todos do
    Repo.all(Todo)
    |> preload(:author)
  end
```

Addtionally you should use `TodoElixir.Main.Todo` instead of `Main.Todo` and `TodoElixir.User.Author` instead of `User.Author`

Comment: The migration you showed works only with one-to-one relation, if you have multiple todos then the correct way is to reference author from the todos table

Comment: request hangs if I use TodoElixir.Main.Todo

Comment: @gyc : I updated answer. has_many should be remove because Author has many todos. we don't need to specify it on Migration of Author. And it should be preloaded author on list_todos

Comment: I updated my question at the same time and made the same changes as you. I get no error but the JSON response doesn't have Author field in it. (I see the query for Author in the console)